# How would I identify between MSR Wisperlite and Wisperlite International stoves?

Tags: gear, backpacking, stoves

About three years ago, I picked up a used "MSR Wisperlite" for a great price.  At the time, I was not aware of the difference between the classic and the International versions of the stove.  Since purchase, I have only used white gas as a fuel.

As far as I can tell, these two stoves are nearly identical.  Current diagrams available on the manufacturer site show slightly different designs of the stand, but this may have been changed over time.  My stand is wire, as opposed to what appears to be stamped aluminum on the current version of the International.

The one notable difference between the two models appears to be the presence of a metallic wick in the priming pan on the International version.

Given that my stove has this wick, I suspect that I have an International model.  Is there any way I can confirm this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it has a wick in the priming pan it is most likely an international. The other main difference is the fuel tube on the international is slightly larger diameter. Although, this would be hard to tell without a comparison.

However, as I commented to ShemSeger's answer there is a different diameter nozzle for kerosene. Therefore if you don't have this nozzle I wouldn't try and use kerosene. You can probably get new nozzles from MSR. I think there are some in one of the service kits, but didn't check if they are the right ones for Kerosene.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to have both stoves that you're talking about. They look pretty much identical, but you're right that the wick is in the international stove, the whitegas-only stove does not have the wick. The international stove also has a brass sleeve over the coil of pipe that directs the liquid fuel through the element where it's vapourised, the whitegas-only whisperlite does not have the sleeve either. If you're still uncertain, you can simply try using your stove with kerosene, if it's the international stove it'll work just fine, but you'll probably notice that it doesn't start as easily, that's because kerosene needs more heat to reach it's flash point. I think that's the biggest difference between the two, is just getting it started, the wick and sleeve on the international stove aid in heating the kerosene to a vapour. You can't damage it by putting kerosene in it, even if it isn't the international, it'll just sputter and flame and get black from not burning right, but as soon as you put white gas back in it it'll clean it right out.

Comment: The international has a different jet for kerosene and white gas. If you try and use kerosene without changing the nozzle you'll probably just block it.

Comment: @nivag ... mine didn't come with an extra nozzle.